# Hide out of stock products via cron job in Prestashop

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I'm running the code bellow via cron jobs in order to disable out-of-stock products from been displayed on my web site. Could anyone who knows the prestashop's database structure helps me to add an exception for 2 product categories with  id 2 & 5 so the script dose not disable products from those categories?

```
<?php
  require_once('./../config/config.inc.php');
  $sql = "UPDATE "._DB_PREFIX_."product_shop SET visibility='none' WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."stock_available WHERE quantity<=0)";
   if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($sql)) die('error!');
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This is the code in case someone else wants to use it. It works with Prestashop 8 and hides the out-of-stock products except the products assigned to category 5.

```
<?php
require_once('./../config/config.inc.php');

    $sqlDisable = "UPDATE "._DB_PREFIX_."product_shop SET visibility='none' WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."stock_available WHERE quantity<=0) AND id_product NOT IN (SELECT id_product FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."category_product WHERE id_category =5)";
    $sqlEnable = "UPDATE "._DB_PREFIX_."product_shop SET visibility='both' WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."stock_available WHERE quantity>0) AND id_product NOT IN (SELECT id_product FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."category_product WHERE id_category =5)";

    $resultSqlDisable = Db::getInstance()->execute($sqlDisable);
        if (!$resultSqlDisable) {
            echo "Error disabling products: " . Db::getInstance()->getMsgError();
        }

    $resultSqlEnable = Db::getInstance()->execute($sqlEnable);
        if (!$resultSqlEnable) {
            echo "Error enabling products: " . Db::getInstance()->getMsgError();
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your query by adding a WHERE condition to check in **ps_category_product** table which **id_product**(s) are not in your id_categories list.

If you want just check by predefined/default product categories, you can just check **id_default_category** field in **ps_product_shop**.